# How do I respond to two different KeyEvents Simultaneously?

Tags: java, game-physics, keylistener, keyevent, game-development

So I am basically creating a platformer game in java. Here is a simple question. Can I respond to two different KeyEvents simultaneously? For example, I am pressing the right arrow key and my player is moving right. Now, I want my player to jump but keep moving right. For this I would need to respond to two different KeyEvents simultaneously. How do I achieve this? I have not tried any code yet because I don't know where to start with. Thank you for the answer in advance.

Comment: Depends on the framework you're using, e.g. AWT, Swing or JavaFX

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that "*I haven't tried any code yet*" is the forbitten sentence on this site... Also, you should post questions like that here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use seperate "KeyDown" and "KeyUp"-events and set state values for your player.

You need a State-Machine for your player.

```
public class KeyboardListener extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

public KeyboardListener() {
    addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        System.out.println("Right key pressed");
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        System.out.println("Left key pressed");
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        System.out.println("Right key Released");
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        System.out.println("Left key Released");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new KeyboardListener();
}
}
```

Use the keyPressed and keyReleased-EventHandlers from the KeyListener Interface and save your current player states like walking, jumping, walk_left, walk_right etc as booleans for example.

In your mainloop you can check what state your player is in and change its coordinates. Like:

```
if(player.left) { player.x += speed } //etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use Threads and then add pressed keys to a list the player physics class.

```
public class KeysListener implements KeyListener
    ...
    //FIRST THREAD
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            public void keyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                 int key = e.getKeyCode();
                 //TODO ADD KEY TO A LIST IN THE CLASS THAT HANDLES YOUR PHYSYICS
            }
        }
    }).start();
    //SECOND THREAD
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            public void keyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                 int key = e.getKeyCode();
                 //TODO ADD KEY TO A LIST IN THE CLASS THAT HANDLES YOUR PHYSICS
            }
        }
    }).start();
...
}
```

Add as many threads as the number of simultaneous keys you require.